# Getting text-only content from non-English website

Tags: java, python, web-scraping, web-crawler, non-english

I am trying to get the text-only contents of a non-English website. For example, I want to get the hindi contents of http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/

For text dump of an English website, I use `wget` to fetch the contents. Then use an HTML parser for removing the HTML tags and give me clean text.

What are the equivalent tools for working on a non-English website?

This is just some pet project that I'm exploring. Speed is not much of a concern. I would code in Linux environment and preferably use Python or Java or C/C++ (in that order).

Comment: Could you be more precise concerning what you mean by "non-english" website.

Comment: By "non-english", I meant that the content is in some other language. Like http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/ is in Hindi. I'm interested in web-pages which have text in Indian languages.

Comment: Why do you think that the tools should be any different for a different language? Have you tried the wget/HTML-parser approach on a a Hindi website? What happened?

Comment: I have just tried with python urllib and apparently there is no problem.

Comment: *For text dump of an English website, I use wget to fetch the contents. Then use an HTML parser for removing the HTML tags and give me clean text. What are the equivalent tools for working on a non-English website?* I'd say they are wget for fetching the contents, then an HTML parser for removing the HTML tags and giving you clean text.

Comment: I just tried wget then read the output on emacs and the hindi text is here and you can parse like you did before with your english page.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the method you're using to parse HTML falls down when encountering unicode. There's a module called BeautifulSoup that's great for parsing all manner of websites, and it handles unicode just fine. Try interactively:

```
>>> import urllib, BeautifulSoup
>>> html = urllib.urlopen( 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/' ).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup( html )
>>> print soup.find( 'title' ).contents
[u'BBC Hindi - \u092a\u0939\u0932\u093e \u092a\u0928\u094d\u0928\u093e']
```

My terminal can't print these characters, but however you usually display Hindi text should work here as well.

Comment: Why do you think that wget can't work? If he already has a parser that should work also.

Comment: @froody: The OP hasn't shown us his code, hasn't told us what doesn't work for him with a Hindi page ... are you channelling him or just guessing when you say "It sounds like the method you're using to parse HTML falls down when encountering unicode"?

Comment: @John, I am just guessing. But the point is that with just a couple lines of code he can accomplish what he wants. Presumably that's helpful to the OP.

Comment: @lc2817, wget could work too. It's just more code in a simple example. How you download the data doesn't matter.

Comment: @froody: Even more helpful would be sussing out why his wget approach is not working, if indeed he has really actually tried it out.